# Is it possible to hide HTML comments from being outputted to the browser?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm using a PHP e-commerce script which is full of comments which are visible to the user if they were to view the source. It doesn't look professional. The comments are everywhere, and it would not be practical to remove them manually.

Is there a way to disable the comments from being displayed via Apache?

The comments I am refering to are the ones like this:

`<!-- Start of some script -->`

`<!-- End of some script -->`

Comment: You should probably be looking at [programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503871/best-way-to-automatically-remove-comments-from-php-code) solutions for this. Either that or deployment tools.

Comment: Duncan below is right that very few people look at the source; you can look at things like [page speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-comment-remove) or you can [use a proxy](https://www.cloudflare.com/features-optimizer) that does it for you. But if your only motivation is because "somebody might look at the source" your priorities are in the wrong place. Note that requests for product recomendations are off topic, so don't expect 10 different answers with 10 different vendor-solutions.

Comment: @Reaces don't know what to say - fire your devs? Why are end-users seeing html comments describing sensitive information? Script files definitely should have comments; PHP files should not be outputting html comments with that kind of info (ever). Also note I gave 2 suggestions as to how to remove comments :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really worry about your source code not "looking professional" - very few people view the source.

I don't think there's a way to do this via Apache, and if there is a way it's definitely not a good idea (performance-wise and generally).

If you want to batch remove the comments from your source files, I would recommend using [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed) with the pattern `s/<!--.*-->//g`:

```
cd /path/to/website
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/<!--.*-->//g'
```

Comment: "I would recommend using sed with the pattern `s/<!--.*-->//g`." - How exactly do you expect that to work?

Comment: @AD7six Updated.

Comment: @AD7six there is a copy-and-paste command to achieve OP's goal, what more do you want?

Comment: @duncan if you're going to answer a question like this (imo a bad idea) - read the question. "it would not be practical to remove them manually" - So the OP doesn't want to do that. In any event applying your sed command to script files can easily break things e.g. of ONE example: `<!-- [if IE ]>`.

Comment: ""it would not be practical to remove them manually" - So the OP doesn't want to do that" I didn't suggest doing it manually. That's a good point about the conditional comments though.

Comment: Good point @AD7six - Could cause some issues there.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a minifying output filter. Something like:

- https://code.google.com/p/minify/ - this can be integrated in your application.
- https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module - to be installed in apache. No application change
- http://mod-tidy.sourceforge.net/ - to be installed in apache. No application change

You can also think to cache parts of the output of the minify if the minify+tempalte process is slow. But this could mean a redesign of the application.